# What is the correct way to fail at compile-time if ARC is off?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm working on some Objective-C code I expect to spin off into a library or at least share with some other people. It requires ARC to use, and if ARC is not enabled, it will leak memory.

What is the correct way to make the code fail to compile if ARC is turned off?

Comment: A big fat red warning on the library's homepage.

Comment: I'd like to downvote that comment, and tell off anyone who refuses to use `static_assert` and `#warning` and `#error` and all the other useful tools we have to enforce assumptions about the compilation environment. Documentation like that is unenforceable, unnatural, and makes you repeat yourself.

Comment: @Joe: Are you really suggesting that your library should simply fail to compile without giving the user the chance to find that out _beforehand_?

Comment: @Josh: I'm saying the library should fail to compile _when it won't work_. Worrying about anything beyond when you haven't first solved that is premature optimization.

Comment: I agree that it should fail to compile, but why wouldn't you _also_ put "Won't work unless compiled using ARC" in the docs? That's not repeating yourself any more than the `-[NSMutableDictionary removeObjectForKey:]` docs saying "raises if key is nil" is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check for ARC at compile time with

```
#if __has_feature(objc_arc)
```

Comment: (+1) Confused why someone would have down-voted this answer. I mean it is the correct answer to the question as asked. Of course you can offer alternative approaches (suggest documentation and static libraries) but none of these will prevent a user in possession of the source code from compiling it incorrectly.

Comment: @idz Maybe because this is only about detecting the problem. MartinR left out the `#error`. Anyway, this is the correct answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think a cleaner approach would be to compile the library as a static library. As ARC will incorporate the release calls according to the rules into the compiled library, it doesnt matter from that point on, if the project it is added to is ARC or MRC — so no hassle for the library user.

Comment: This is definitely the approach I would recommend when sharing ARC code.